# add a class to php variable

Tags: php, wordpress, class, variables

I need help with the syntax on how to add a class to the $output variable I need to echo out here.  Not good with PHP and I am trying to add a breadcrumb divider so I thought I could do it with css 'content:' if only I could add the class. I tried adding &class=something but it didn't work. Also sticking a '' in the $output variable and that was no good either. Thanks in advance.

```
$output = wp_list_pages('echo=0&title_li=&child_of=' );

  if (is_page( )) {
    $page = $post->ID;
    if ($post->post_parent) {
      $page = $post->post_parent;
    }
    $children=wp_list_pages( 'echo=0&title_li=&child_of=' . $page );
    if ($children) {
      $output = wp_list_pages ('echo=0&title_li=&child_of=' . $page );
    }
  }
echo $output;
```

Comment: According to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages the function wp_list_pages() accepts an array, so I don't know why you are inputting a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understood right, you can switch to html like this:

```
...
}
?>
<div class="OutputClass" >
  <?php echo $output; ?>
</div>
```

Or you can echo HTML in PHP, like this:

```
...
}
echo '<div class="OutputClass" >';
echo $output;
echo '</div>';
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example:

```
echo '<ul class="ClassUL">';
wp_list_pages(); // echo is TRUE by default
echo '</ul>';
```

Will output all arguments inside `<ul>` tags.

In case you haven't, check [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#Include_Pages_in_List)  link for the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Felipe. That puts the class before the list, instead of to each of the list items. I changed it to <li> but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You can accept the answer if you like it. ¿Why don't you, are you waiting for another answer?